# XCart 4 coupon code for free shipping AND free item (100% discount)

Tags: ecommerce

I am running XCart 4 Classic. We need to set up a coupon code that will allow for Free Shipping + 100% off (free product). An additional requirement is that this will apply to certain products but I know I can filter this in the “Cart Contains the product…” section. How do I combine the two coupon types (Free Shipping and % OFF)?

P.S. I wasnt sure if this was the right SE for this question, but the help section specifically says, "*Questions about other CMSs may be asked here on Pro Webmasters.*"

Comment: It's unlikely you can by default without using a plug-in or development which is considered off-topic.